# AQL for pattern matching

Tags: aql

i want to write an AQL FOR arrangodb TO FETCH all the results matching with a particuler input

i tried something like this 
for all the locations which starts with GR

```
FOR con IN countries
FILTER "%GR%" LIKE con.location 
RETURN {
"name" : con.name
}
```

but it retruns empty .and it has the location starting with GR.
i'm new to AQL ,any idea what i'm missing

Answer (score 0):

fount it , using REGEX_TEST

```
LET con  = "US"
FOR con IN countries
 LET match = REGEX_TEST(con.location, con ,true)
FILTER match == true                     
RETURN {
"name" : con.name
}
```